# how should I order my statement in a short circuit and?

Tags: python, recursion, short-circuiting

hmm I am doing a [question on leetcode to verify if something is a symmetric tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/symmetric-tree/) and I have this one line of code:

```
if A.val == B.val and Issymmetric(A.left, B.right) and Issymmetric(A.right,B.left):
    return True
```

basically if A's root value is the same as B's root value and A's left subtree is symmetric to B's right subtree plus A's right subtree is symmetric to B's left subtree, then I conclude A,B is symmetric

however this code runs very slow : **80ms** on leetcode
but if I change the order of the if statement to:

```
if Issymmetric(A.left, B.right) and Issymmetric(A.right,B.left) and A.val == B.val:
    return True
```

this code with same logic, but takes only **52ms**, I kind of assumed that comparing the root values should be done before I exhaustively process the entire left/right subtrees (in general this is more efficient, it can possibly save a lot of recursive calls)

**TL;DR**
this gives me an impression that python evaluate ***short circuit and*** in reverse order, so I did a little test on my local environment:

```
def f1():
   print 1
   return True
def f2():
   print 2
   return True
if f1() and f2():
   pass
# but the output I got is 1,2...
```

I am confused, if the order of a short circuit is from left to right, why is there a huge performance difference between my code?

I can upload my entire IsSymmetric() function, if it is necessary
**I did some further testing, I think 80ms is just a glitch on leetcode,thanks**

Comment: Why would you think it's doing it in reverse?  if the == takes 28ms, and ISsymmetric takes 52ms each, the results you are getting make sense for a left-to-right short circuit evaluation.

Comment: What do the inputs look like? If the trees are very similar by the root node and differ only at the extremities of the tree then this is why your code will be slow. It's like asking why a method to check equality of lists is slow when they only differ by their last element.

Comment: it did some testing, **80ms** looks like a one time thing on leetcode...it is now back to normal, should I delete this post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question, that goes into some subtle areas.

When looking at a condition, as well as the speed of the condition, you need to look at how discriminating it is. I.e., wheether it immediately gives the "right" answer, or if you need to continue looking at other conditions.

It may be better to have a slow but discriminating condition first, depending on a number of factors.

Consider two functions:

```
def f1(c):
    sleep(20)
    return (c % 2) == 0

def f2(c):
    sleep(25)
    return (c % 4) == 0
```

`f1()` is fast, but not very discriminating, while `f2()` is slower, but more discriminating. Consider the two expressions `f1(c) and f2(c)` verses `f2(c) and f1(c)` for `c in 0..3`

```
=== ===== ====
c   exp1  exp2
=== ===== ====
0   20+25 25+20
1   20+0  25+0
2   20+25 25+0
3   20+0  25+0
=== ===== ====
    130   120
```

Note how having the `slow` condition first results in a (slightly) smaller total time.

Comment: interesting, it is true that the recursive function is more likely to fail since it is comparing the entire subtree as opposed to just comparing a node, I guess if the disagreement (nodes that causes non-symmetry ) is deep (close to the leafs), it make sense...I submitted the same code on leetcode, it now shows 52ms....I guess I will never know if its the input or simply a cache issue on their website

Answer (score 0):

Python `if` statements will break at the first sign of falsity. ie.

```
if a == True and b == True:
```

will break if `a` is False, and will only evaluate `b` if `a` is True.

So, if you have a series of comparisons, like you do, and want to optimize for speed, place your most common case first.

Comment: are you saying that I should do IsSymmetric() on left and right subtree, then do the `A.val == B.val`, but I was thinking even if left and right subtree are indeed symmetric, if `A.val != B.val`, then we are just wasting recursions, is my logic wrong?

Comment: What I'm saying is if the most common `break` in your logic would be `Issymmetric(A.left, B.right)` then that should precede the rest. However, that type of optimization should only be done once you've properly profiled your code, are sure of the results, and even care about the performance optimizations.